# Ubuntu 20.04 not booting on Raspberry Pi 4 (external SSD)

Tags: boot, usb, 20.04, ssd, raspberrypi

I'm having a problem booting Ubuntu 20.04 on my Raspberry Pi.
I'm using a
RPi 4 with 2gb of RAM and a
Kingston A400 SSD.
I downloaded Ubuntu (64 bit) and flashed it to my SSD with Etcher. But when I boot, I get a list of "missing environment variable: bootfile". It also says that USB is stopped. At the end of the list, it says "U-Boot>". I don't think its the SSD, because it's run other OS's on the Pi before. And using the same process, I've been able to get Ubuntu to run using a micro sd card. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The OS is intended to be run from the SD card slot.  Also, you can't run the AMD64 version of Ubuntu on a raspberry pi.  You need to flash the preinstalled server image for armhf or arm64 to a SD card.  That is the only supported way of installing Ubuntu to a raspi

Comment: Jeff Geerling has a guide and a video about this: https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2020/im-booting-my-raspberry-pi-4-usb-ssd

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Flashed Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS for ARM 64-bit to a microSD card, then getting tons of errors at initial boot.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1 doesn't boot on my pi 4. I am running headless, no monitor, so no idea what was going on. The pi turns on and green light flicked once or two, then off, nothing. However, ubuntu 20.10 64bit boots ok, no hack required.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this solution works for everyone but I tried the following:

- Flashing the os on my external ssd attached via usb.
- Flashing an "untouched" ubuntu 20.04.1 server image on a sd card.
- Insert / attach both.
- Hit power button.

My Pi 4 boots into the system installed on the usb storage device. lsblk shows that the sd card isn't mounted after successful boot.

When the sd card isn't inserted the boot process fails as described above.

Comment: This fix should work for everyone, but an additional step would make this a cleaner, safer solution. Flash the same image to both the SD card and the USB drive, as described, but then delete the boot partition from the USB drive and the system partition from the SD card. This eliminates the risk of the OS mounting the wrong partition down the road. It's never good to run a system where multiple partitions have the same UUID (always a recipe for a mess). Anyways, I just did this with my RPi 4 and it seems to be running fine. Thanks for taking the time to share your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your power supply. Not sure how much current your SSD needs. I changed power supply and now it boots.

My boot **fail** config:

```
Pi 3, external USB SSD, AXT-Raspi, 2.5Amp PS with USB connector and switch inline to micro USB connector.
```

My boot **success** config:

```
Pi 3, external USB SSD, AXT-Raspi, 2.5Amp PS straight to micro USB connector.
```

Even after successful boot, I still get a number of Under voltage warnings on the ubuntu command line. In my case it is the ATX-Raspi power button. It is not passing enough power to my Pi 3 to run the external drive. Works fine without the ATX-Raspi or the SSD.